# Issue with html tag alignment

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am new to html,css and unable to figure out how to align like,comment span element to the bottom left of the parent div and share bottom to the bottom right. and make the p element in the middle of the parent div. I have attached the css and html code. please help

React Code

```
 render() {
        return (
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <div className="row justify-content-center">
                    <div className="post-holder shadow-sm p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
                        <h4>I am a data scientist and yes, you did r</h4>
                        <div className='m-2'>
                        <span className="username ">@username</span>
                        <span className="postdate float-right">1 Day ago</span>
                        </div>

                        <p className="align-self-center">
                        But the truth is that data scientists typically “spend 1–2 hours a week looking for a new job” as stated in this article by the Financial Times. Furthermore, the article also states that “Machine learning specialists topped its list of deve
                        </p>
                        <div className ="post-actions">
                        <span className="fa fa-heart fa-lg post-like"> 299</span>
                        <span className="fa fa-comment fa-lg post-comment"> 299</span>
                        <span className="fa fa-share fa-lg post-share"> 299</span>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

css code

```
body {
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
}

.post-holder {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0px 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.username {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #899bb4;
}

.post-actions {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2rem;
}

.post-share {
  right: 2rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose both the like and comment spans inside one `<div>` and share span in another div and provide float:right to the latter div.

```
   <div className="post-actions">
    <div>
      <span className="fa fa-heart fa-lg post-like"> 299</span>
      <span className="fa fa-comment fa-lg post-comment"> 299</span>
    </div>
    <div style={{ "float": "right" }}>
       <span className="fa fa-share fa-lg post-share"> 299</span>
    </div>
   </div>
```

To keep the `<p>` at the center use a certain width and margin:"0 auto" .

```
 <p className="align-self-center" style={{width:"50%",margin:"0 auto"}}>
   But the truth is that data scientists typically “spend 1–2 hours a week looking for a new job” as stated in this article by the Financial Times. Furthermore, the article also states that “Machine learning specialists topped its list of deve
 </p>
```

Comment: thanks for helping, i want the p tag to be center vertically

Comment: please check the link [link](https://imgur.com/a/QqnNVpb) the share button is not in right

Comment: Please remove position : absolute from .post-actions

Comment: For vertical center alignment use this : 
<div style={{ height: "200px", position: "relative"}}>
   <p className="align-self-center" style={{margin: "0",position: "absolute",top: "50%",transform: "translateY(-50%)"}}>But the truth is that data scientists typically “spend 1–2 hours a week looking for a new job” as stated in this article by the Financial Times. Furthermore, the article also states that “Machine learning specialists topped its list of deve </p>
</div>

See this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_center-vertical.asp for better understanding

Comment: please check the [link](https://imgur.com/a/QoPSYvc) the share button and like button or not in same line. if i remove position: absolute then the bottom param does not work.

Thanks a lot for helping me

Comment: add float:"left" to the former div.
   <div className="post-actions">
       <div style={{"float":"left"}}>
           <span className="fa fa-heart fa-lg post-like"> 299</span>
           <span className="fa fa-comment fa-lg post-comment"> 299</span>
        </div>
        <div style={{ "float": "right" }}>
           <span className="fa fa-share fa-lg post-share" style={{ right: "2rem"}}> 
             299
           </span>
       </div>
     </div>